# Find tags with numbers and replace it with numbers

Tags: java, regex, xml

I want to replace whole tags to numbers from those tags.

For example:

```
<o:15> My text.
<o:16> My new text.
<o:17> Another text.
```

Change to:

```
15 My text.
16 My new text.
17 Another text.
```

I can find number from tag by `<o:\\b\\d+\\b>` expression, but how can I replace all tags and put their numbers?

Comment: your first example miss closing tags, is it okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `replaceAll` method of `String` class:

```
String newText = text.replaceAll("<o:\\b(\\d+)\\b>", "$1");
```

Firstly, we're creating capturing group with setting braces around `\d+`, then we're using this group in output. You can read more about capturing groups [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("15 My text.".replaceAll("<o:\\b(\\d+)\\b>", "$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to parse or alter markup is generally considered as a bad idea.

This said, you can use the following to replace your tags:

```
String text = "<o:15> My text.\r\n<o:16> My new text.\r\n<o:17> Another text.";
//                                  | start pattern
//                                  |  | group 1: any number of digits
//                                  |  |         | back reference
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("<o:(\\d+)>", "$1"));
```

**Output**

```
15 My text.
16 My new text.
17 Another text.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have made regex correctly then you just have to group the regex as

```
<o:(\\b\\d+\\b)> and just replace the whole regex with $1
```

replaceAll could be used